# How to get the value of unchecked and checked checkboxes

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a list of checkboxes and want to return their values on submit. I can do this easily for the checked ones, but not for the unchecked? Here's my code so far:

Code to get all address books and existing user address books and output as checkboxes:

```
foreach ($ch2_response as $ab) {
    if ($ab['visibility'] == "Public") { 
        if (in_array($ab['name'], $userBooks)) { ?>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="addressBooks[]" value="<?php echo $ab['id']; ?>"><?php echo $ab['name']; ?>
                </label>
            </div>
     <?php   } else { ?>
             <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="addressBooks[]" value="<?php echo $ab['id']; ?>"><?php echo $ab['name']; ?>
                </label>
            </div>
      <?php  }
    }
}
```

`
Code to check user's new choices:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    address_books();
}
function address_books() {
    $book = $_POST['addressBooks'];
    if (!isset($book)) {
        $N = count($book);

        echo("You did not select $N book(s): ");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
            echo($book[$i] . " ");
        }
    } else {
        $N = count($book);

        echo("You selected $N book(s): ");
        for ($i = 0; $i < $N; $i++) {
            echo($book[$i] . " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If a checkbox is not checked it will not be returned.

Comment: I get that @Dave - but I need the ID's (values) from the unchecked boxes too so I can go on to unsubscribe the user from the address books they didn't check.

Comment: Then you need to keep track of what was checked when you show the page and compare what is still checked when the page is submitted. You aren't going to get back unchecked boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the values of unchecked checkboxes. The browser won't submit them.

You can add a hidden input field with the same name right before each `checkbox` and give it the false value that you want.

```
<input type="hidden" name="addressBooks" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="addressBooks" value="1">
```

When the checkbox is unchecked the browser submit the hidden value to the server

Comment: thanks, i've seen this suggesstion elsewhere and tried, but it's not working, it's adding duplicates and doesnt give the value I need. will add the full code that's outputting the checkboxes into my questions

Comment: Oh, In your case won't work because you handle addressBooks as an array